# I am having weather data in grib2 format and i want to convert it into json format Is it possible to conversion using node.js?

Tags: node.js, netcdf, node.js-addon, pygrib, grib-api

I am having weather data in grib2 format and i want to convert it into json format or csv. I know the languages PHP , node.js. Is it possible to conversion using these technologies?

Answer (score 0):

Using Nodejs try this package may help you 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grib2json